# only allow single item in Woocommerce cart by using filter woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation

Tags: woocommerce, cart

If you want to restrict customer to add single item in Woocommerce cart , then you can use filter "woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter is defined in the following location(s).

```
/includes/class-wc-ajax.php
```

Allow to add only single item in WooCommerce cart

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'restrict_only_one_item_in_cart' );

 function restrict_only_one_item_in_cart($cart_item_data) {

   global $woocommerce;
   $item_count = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;

   if($item_count > 0){
      wc_add_notice( 'Sorry. Only one item is allowed.If you would like to add another, please remove the item in the cart.', 'error' );
      return false;
   }
   return $cart_item_data;
}
```